# std::stod throws out_of_range error for a string that should be valid

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    stringstream ss;
    double ad = 7.63918e-313;
    ss << ad;
    cout<<ss.str()<<endl;
    //you will see that the above double is valid, and maps to the specified string

    //but stod cannot map it back
    stod("7.63918e-313");
    //terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
}
```

Run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy1MT1iQM

"7.63918e-313" will result from serializing a double, but stod cannot deserialize it. What's going on here? The smallest possible double is supposedly around 10^−324.

Is there a pair of functions somewhere in the stdlib that can reliably map doubles back and forth from stringification? Shouldn't there be?

The plot thickens. We have two bizarre observations.

- `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` cannot be parsed by stod either.
- `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is not the minimum double. Our double is smaller, and I find we can get smaller doubles by simply dividing min, so it's not that my double is anomalous or anything https://onlinegdb.com/rJvilljQz

I am very concerned.

Comment: Since floating point typess are not held precisely there will rarely  be a round-trip to string and back.

Comment: You could output a byte representation as a serialized form that would round-trip, but that would not be .meaningful to humans, too.

Comment: `7.63918e-313` is out of range.  `std::numeric_limits<double>::min() = 2.22507e-308`.

Comment: “We have found a positive double that is smaller than what the standard library claims is the smallest double.”  NO!  The double your are using is no longer *exactly* representable as a double.

Comment: No, look at the updated test code. (min > ad && ad > 0) verifies. It's not even about representation.

Comment: @mako Yes, you can compare two doubles, regardless of whether they are *exactly* representable or not.  If you are really so keen on having this value back, just read it as long double and narrow it down again: `double d = std::stold("7.63918e-313");`

Comment: @HenriMenke: Re: “The double your are using is no longer exactly representable as a double.” That does not make any sense. If you have a `double`, the value of it is exactly representable as a `double`. It is itself an exact representation of its value.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts — floating-point values **are** represented precisely. **Real numbers** are not, because there are too many of them. It’s possible to write conversions from floating-point to decimal text and back that will get back the original value. This problem was first solved about 50 years ago. Going the other way, string to floating-point to string and getting the original value, is not, in general, possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Converting “7.63918e-313”

The C++ standard allows conversions of strings to `double` to report underflow if the result is in the subnormal range even though it is representable.

7.63918•10<sup>-313</sup> is within the range of `double`, but it is in the subnormal range. The C++ standard says `stod` calls `strtod` and then defers to the C standard to define `strtod`. The C standard indicates that `strtod` may underflow, about which it says “The result underflows if the magnitude of the mathematical result is so small that the mathematical result cannot be represented, without extraordinary roundoff error, in an object of the specified type.” That is awkward phrasing, but it refers to the rounding errors that occur when subnormal values are encountered. (Subnormal values are subject to larger relative errors than normal values, so their rounding errors might be said to be extraordinary.)

Thus, a C++ implementation is allowed by the C++ standard to underflow for subnormal values even though they are representable.

## Converting std::numeric_limits::min()

Regarding your observation that `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` “cannot be parsed” either (I presume you mean it also reports underflow), this may be due to the fact that you converted `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` to a string containing a decimal numeral, and that decimal numeral was not an exact representation of `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`. If it was rounded down, it is slightly less than `min()`, and hence it is also in the subnormal range. Thus, attempting to convert that decimal numeral back to a `double` may correctly report it is below the normal range.

## std::numeric_limits::min() is not the minimum double

Regarding your observation that `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is not the minimum `double`, that is correct. `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is specified by the C++ standard to be the minimum positive normal value. There may be subnormal values below it.

## Normal and subnormal values

For IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, the normal range is from 2<sup>-1022</sup> to 2<sup>1024</sup>-2<sup>971</sup>. Within this range, every number is represented with a signficand (the fraction portion of the floating-point representation) that has a leading 1 bit followed by 52 additional bits, and so the error that occurs when rounding any real number in this range to the nearest representable value is at most 2<sup>-53</sup> times the position value of the leading bit.

In additional to this normal range, there is a subnormal range from 2<sup>-1074</sup> to 2<sup>-1022</sup>-2<sup>-1074</sup>. In this interval, the exponent part of the floating-point format has reached its smallest value and cannot be decreased any more. To represent smaller and smaller numbers in this interval, the significand is reduced below the normal minimum of 1. It starts with a 0 and is followed by 52 additional bits. In this interval, the error that occurs when rounding a real number to the nearest representable value may be larger than 2<sup>-53</sup> times the position value of the leading bit. Since the exponent cannot be decreased any further, numbers in this interval have increasing numbers of leading 0 bits as they get smaller and smaller. Thus the relative errors involved with using these numbers grows.

For whatever reasons, the C++ has said that implementations may report underflow in this interval. (The IEEE-754 standard defines underflow in complicated ways and also allows implementations some choices.)

Comment: I quoted your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414829/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Sure, that is fine. When I saw that question, it rang a bell; I knew I had written this previously. But I did not have time to look it up before leaving the house. I am glad it was correctly cross-referenced.

Answer (score 2):

The value you are trying to read as a double, `7.63918e-313`, is smaller than the minimal value that is representable by a double on your architecture.  On my architecture this is `2.22507e-308` and can be obtained using `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`.

From the standard: [[string.conversions]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.conversions#6)

> Throws out_­of_­range if `strtof`, `strtod`, or `strtold` sets `errno` to `ERANGE` or if the converted value is outside the range of representable values for the return type.

That is to say, mapping doubles back on forth to string is possible using `std::to_string` and `std::stod` (or stringstreams) given that they are representable.

---

Instead you could use [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/libs/lexical_cast/) for parsing which does not seem to have these limitations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() {
    double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>("7.63918e-313");
    std::cout << d << "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qPyrxqhVZMd2QhTm)</kbd>

Another alternative is [Boost.Spirit](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    double d = 0;
    std::string input = "7.63918e-313";
    x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), x3::double_, d);
    std::cout << d << "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DvFMs8TJMdjXyXwv)</kbd>

Comment: While this is very helpful, it does not solve my problem, nor C++'s problem. Hmm... Is it possible that the double I had popping up in my data was a result of a random, out of bounds write, or a cosmic ray, and that it shouldn't be able to pop up during normal execution?

Comment: @mako Your problem is limited by machine architecture.  Switch to `long double` and hope that it's longer than `double` or use a multiprecision library.

Comment: This is not the answer.
Exact representability has little to do with size. The number "3" has no exact representation in floating point either, but you'll still be able to map it back and forth between strings because the parsers are clever.
Why do you think the documentation is talking about representability in decimal string notation? It's about representability in memory, I would guess. Decimal strings have no minimums. They can be as long and as detailed as they want.

Your supposed minimum decimal representable number also cannot be parsed by stod https://onlinegdb.com/Hk8fIgsmG

Comment: @mako You're right, the second part of my answer was not really helpful.  I edited it to show a way to parse such a number as a double anyway.

Comment: For the record, 3 is pretty easy to represent. It can be tricky to compute exactly though.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is not the minimum representable value (actually, that is zero, but it is not the minimum representable positive value either). It is the minimum positive **normalized** value. There may be subnormal values below it. For IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, the smallest positive value is about 4.94065645841247e-324.

Comment: @mako: 3 is exactly represented in IEEE-754 64-bit binary with the bits 0x4008000000000000.

Comment: (I should have said that zero is the minimum in absolute value, rather than minimum value. The minimum representable value is actually -∞.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the specification of `strtod` (which is referred from the specification of `std::strod`), if the conversion *underflows*, the function is allowed, but not required to set `errno` to `ERANGE`. It is implementation-defined whether `errno` is set in this case.

In your example the conversion does underflow. Apparently, in your implementation `strtod` sets `errno` to `ERANGE` and `std::stod` unconditionally throws `std::out_of_range` when it sees that `ERANGE` in `errno`.

In a different implementation `strtod` might not set `errno` to `ERANGE` in this case, and `std::stod` would not throw.

Basically, C++ standard library is not guaranteed to properly convert underflowing values. Even if `strtod` decides not to set `errno`, it is still allowed to return the smallest normalized value as a result in this case, instead of your original value.