# Explicit specification of the double precision representation used by compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I've recently come across the problem that `visual-c++` does not seem to be [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) compliant, but instead uses [subnormal representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number). That is, double precision floats in it do not have the usual representation of 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits and 52 explicitly stored significant decimal bits, see below.

[image]

As `gcc` and `clang` are however compliant and consistent cross-platform behaviour is highly desired I would like to know whether it is possible to force `visual-c++` to use the normal representation. Alternatively making `gcc` and `clang` use the subnormal representation would of course also solve the problem.

The issue of the different double representations can be reproduced in [`visual-c++`](https://rextester.com/XXK18577), [`gcc`](https://rextester.com/CDC92891) and [`clang`](https://rextester.com/NUYF91139) using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    try {
        std::stod("8.0975711886543594e-324");
        std::cout << "Subnormal representation.";
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Normal representation.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is a representation specification to produce consitent behaviour in all three cases at all possible?

**Edit:** As [geza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157187/geza) pointed out, this appears a problem in the different implementations of [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), which would then make the question if there is any way to make `std::stod` behave consistently without having to implement a seperate wrapper for it.

Comment: Here, the difference lies in `std::stod`, doesn't it? GCC and clang throw out_of_range for subnormal numbers (which is weird, if you ask me), while msvc doesn't. I even don't understand, why they throw out_of_range for a small number which is truncated to zero. It's definitely not out_of_range. There should be a separate exception for this case.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086830/stdstod-throws-out-of-range-error-for-a-string-that-should-be-valid

Comment: `std::stod` is badly designed. `strtod` can report whether the ERANGE means overflow or underflow. `std::stod` cannot.

Comment: @geza Thanks, edited the post to reflect that its `std::stod`, maybe there's some standard way around the design

Comment: Yes, use `strtod`, which doesn't have this limitation. It behaves not as documented for subnormal numbers: it will return the subnormal value (so, contrary to the doc, it returns a non-zero value, yet sets errno=ERANGE). Which is good for us, because you can get the number you want.

Comment: @geza Yup, did the trick perfectly, all I needed was `std::strtod(cstr, nullptr)`, thanks! If you want to make it into an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `std::stod` is badly designed, because it is not possible to determine what caused the `std::out_of_range` exception.

I'd suggest you to use `strtod` instead. While is not specified in the standard what this function should do for subnormal numbers, it behaves well for subnormal numbers usually (it means that it returns subnormal numbers). The benefit of this function is that it returns a meaningful result for out-of-range situations, so it is possible to determine the cause of out-of-range.

If you want to handle out of range situations, you'll need to check `errno` for `ERANGE`. Note, that if a subnormal/zero number is a result, then maybe `errno` will be set to `ERANGE`, which you should ignore (you can check this out with `fpclassify`).

So the logic is something like this:

```
double r = strtod(string, &end);
// here, check for end to know about invalid strings

if (errno==ERANGE) { // out-of-range (overflow, underflow)
    int c = fpclassify(r);
    if (c!=FP_SUBNORMAL&&c!=FP_ZERO) { // let's filter out underflow cases
        // "real" out of range handling here, just overflow
    }
}
```