# Inconsistent stringstream behavior when parsing doubles in libc++ and glibc

Tags: c++, parsing, double, stringstream

When compiling the following sample with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dFGIKu1NcU3lhMyv) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yIkRhMHf20XR4UjG)...

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double val;
    std::stringstream ss("6.93758e-310");
    ss >> val;

    std::cout << "fail: " << ss.fail() << std::endl
}
```

...I get different behavior:

1. With gcc, the stream's failbit `ss.fail()` is not set, while
2. for clang it is set

It might be relevant to note that in both cases, `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

Also, locally I get the same behavior with clang and gcc, unless I explicitly use libc++ with clang (`-stdlib=libc++`) instead of glibc.

I am not sure what the correct behavior is, but it feels to me like it should be consistent.

Comment: Why do you want to use a C tool when you are using C++? I don't think the C++ standard requires its errors to be propagated to errno. This means that's up to the standard library implementation.

Comment: Unless documented otherwise, the state of `errno` is always considered indeterminate. Don't check it unless the documentation says it's actually set.

Comment: Interesting.  `6.93758e-310` is subnormal for a 64 bit `double`, so that could be part of the issue.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't make assumptions about `errno` 's state, but I found it curious that it is being set by this operation and figured it might be relevant to indicate why the mismatch occurs.

Comment: This is almost certainly a library issue and not a compiler issue. At least between clang and gcc, you can use either library with either compiler, although setting up an environment which gives you all four choices can be a bit tricky.

Comment: It seems like you're correct, I tested all four options now and `libc++` consistently sets the fail bit while `glibc` does not.

Comment: related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086830/stdstod-throws-out-of-range-error-for-a-string-that-should-be-valid

Comment: Is this is due to (what is to me) an ambiguity in https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/n4791/source/locales.tex#L2648 ("if the field represents a value outside the range of representable values, ios_base::failbit is assigned to err"): whether "outside the range" also includes numbers that are in the representable *interval*, but still not representable?

Comment: @ChristophSommer it would be kinda annoying if unrepresentable inputs like `"0.1"` caused failbit to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviour of input streams extraction operator is specified as follows:

> [istream.formatted.arithmetic] As in the case of the inserters, these extractors depend on the locale’s `num_get<>` ([locale.num.get]) object
>   to perform parsing the input stream data. These extractors behave as formatted input functions (as
>   described in [istream.formatted.reqmts]). After a sentry object is constructed, the conversion occurs as if performed by
>   the following code fragment:
>
> ```
> using numget = num_get<charT, istreambuf_iterator<charT, traits>>;
> iostate err = iostate::goodbit;
> use_facet<numget>(loc).get(*this, 0, *this, err, val);
> setstate(err);
> ```
>
> In the above fragment, loc stands for the private member of the basic_ios class.

[facet.num.get.virtuals] is a bit verbose, but relevant parts are:

> For a double value, the function strtod.
>
> ... if the field represents a value outside the range of representable values, ios_base::failbit
>   is assigned to err.

`strtod` is not specified in the C++ standard, but in the C standard. The relevant bit:

> 7.20.1.3  The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions
>
> §10 If the result underflows (7.12.1), the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether errno acquires the value ERANGE is implementation-defined.

The referred rule:

> 7.12.1  Treatment of error conditions
>
> §5 The  result  underflows  if  the  magnitude  of  the  mathematical  result  is  so  small  that  the mathematical  result  cannot  be  represented,  without  extraordinary  roundoff error, in an object  of  the  specified  type.<sup>204)</sup> If  the  result  underflows,  the  function  returns  an implementation-defined   value   whose   magnitude   is   no   greater   than   the   smallest normalized    positive    number    in    the    specified    type;    if    the    integer    expression math_errhandling  &  MATH_ERRNO is  nonzero,  whether errno acquires  the value ERANGE is      implementation-defined;      if      the      integer      expression math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT is  nonzero,  whether  the  ‘‘underflow’’ floating-point exception is raised is implementation-defined
>
> 204)The  term  underflow here  is  intended  to  encompass  both  ‘‘gradual  underflow’’as in IEC 60559 and also ‘‘flush-to-zero’’underflow.

---

Although C++ does not specify how floating point operations are represented, your system probably uses IEEE-754 (IEC 60559).

IEEE-754 specifies underflow as:

> 7.5.0 (simplified)
>
> The underflow exception shall be signaled when a tiny non-zero result is detected. This shall be when a   non-zero   result  computed   as   though both the exponent range and the precision were unbounded would lie strictly between ±b<sup>emin</sup>.

Where ±b<sup>emin</sup> is the positive or negative **normal** value closest to zero. It also says:

> The implementer shall choose how tininess is detected

---

So, to answer your statement:

> it feels to me like it should be consistent.

That would be nice, but much of the behaviour around underflow is specified to be implementation-defined.

Frankly, the input stream API is constrained, since it doesn't provide a guaranteed access to the rounded value in cases where an underflow has been detected, nor does it provide a way to differentiate an underflow failure from other failures.