# Why floating point conversion not working?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Why floating point conversion is failing for the smallest positive floating point number?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
   std::vector<std::string> testStrings;
   float fmax = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(); // maximum value
   float fmin = std::numeric_limits<float>::min(); // maximum value
   std::cout<<fmax<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<fmin<<std::endl;
   
  float result=0;
  bool status=false;
  //below test cases must pass
  testStrings.push_back("10");
  testStrings.push_back("+10");
  testStrings.push_back(" 10 ");
  testStrings.push_back("10.253165");
  testStrings.push_back("10.253165E12");
  testStrings.push_back("11111111111111111111111");
  testStrings.push_back("2e-123546132222");
  testStrings.push_back("3.40282e+38");
  testStrings.push_back("3.40284e+38");
  testStrings.push_back("1.17549e-38"); // This test case is throwing out of range exception

for(std::string temp:testStrings)
{
std::stof(temp);
}

}
```

I am using the method std::stof for conversion.

Comment: You should post a [mcve].  That means we should be able to take your code, and without *any* changes whatsoever, compile and run the code.

Comment: Question is somewhat incomplete. but odds are good that 1.17549e-38 is being rounded up when printed.

Comment: *I am using the method std::stof for conversion.* -- Where?  [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b044a538bdfaf40).

Comment: I have edited the code. Now please see.

Comment: Remember that floating point numbers are fuzzy. 1.17549e-38 may be parsed to a value ever so slightly out of range and be rejected.

Comment: Use Google's [double-conversion library](https://github.com/google/double-conversion) for accurate conversion between decimal and floating point. The C++ standard provides no guarantees of accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

The program does not use enough digits to represent the minimum normal `float` with sufficient accuracy.

The minimum positive normal number in IEEE-754 binary32 is 2<sup>−126</sup>, which is 1.1754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625•10^<sup>−38</sup>. However, this is not the number the program in the question passes to `strtod`. Instead, it has used only six significant digits, “1.17549e-38”. 1.17549•10<sup>−38</sup> is less than 2<sup>−126</sup>, and it is less than it by so much that converting it to `float` (using the IEEE-754 binary32 format) produces a number less than 2<sup>−126</sup>. The actual number produced is 2<sup>−126</sup> − 31•2<sup>−149</sup>.

So attempting to convert “1.17549e-38” from decimal to float with `strtof` yields a range error, because it is indeed out of range (out of the normal range; the value is representable, but the C++ standard allows out of range errors for results in the subnormal range).

Lesson: Do not use just six digits. Using three more digits, “1.17549435e-38”, is sufficient that the result of conversion is 2<sup>−126</sup>, and no range error is generated. In general, using nine significant decimal digits is sufficient that converting any IEEE-754 binary32 format to decimal and back will yield the original number. (This value, nine, is reported by `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10`.)

See also [std::stod throws out_of_range error for a string that should be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086830/stdstod-throws-out-of-range-error-for-a-string-that-should-be-valid).