# Can't use Java Double.MIN_VALUE 4.9E-324 as a floating point literal in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, floating-point

Running the following JDBC code with SQL Server:

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("select 4.9E-324, ?")) {
    s.setDouble(1, 4.9E-324);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(2));
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
0.0
4.9E-324
```

So, while the bind value is echoed back correctly, the literal is not. How can this be explained? [I've noticed in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> Any float value less than 5E-18 (when set using either the scientific notation of 5E-18 or the decimal notation of 0.0000000000000000050000000000000005) rounds down to 0. This is no longer a restriction as of SQL Server 2016 (13.x).

But I'm using SQL Server 2019

```sql
select @@version
```

Yields:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64) 
Nov  2 2020 18:35:09 
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) <X64>
```

And the latest version of SQL Server's JDBC driver

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Some parsers handle subnormal numbers poorly. [Here is an example we saw in C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086830/stdstod-throws-out-of-range-error-for-a-string-that-should-be-valid/48087390#48087390). You might try `4.941e-324`, as this is slightly above the minimum representable positive value instead of below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [same documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) also lists the range of valid float values to be:

> -1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308

So, the Java `Double.MIN_VALUE` is out of range. This works:

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("select 2.23E-308, ?")) {
    s.setDouble(1, 2.23E-308);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Producing:

```
2.23E-308
2.23E-308
```

It doesn't explain why the bind variable is echoed back correctly, though.

Comment: In `Oracle` this could help for explanation: `select dump(4.9E-130,16) from dual; -- Typ=2 Len=3: 80,5,5b`